# Настройка последовательности ввода в элементы на андроид-приложение

Tags: java, android, xml

Задача: настроить последовательность заполнения полей так что бы сначала вводились данные в поле №1 после его заполнения автоматически в поле №2 и после его заполнения в поле №3. Как это сделать?

[image: телефон]

Comment: Вам нужны атрибуты `nextFocusDown` и `nextFocusRight` плюс, опционально, разные слушатели на поля ввода для запроса фокуса для следующего поля ввода

Answer (score 0):

```
editTextValidity.requestFocus();переводит курсор на указаный едиттейбл

public void afterTextChanged(Editable cardnumber) {//cardnumber
            if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 3) {
                cardnumber.append(" ");
                System.out.println(cardnumber);

            }
            if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 8) {
                cardnumber.append(" ");
                System.out.println(cardnumber);

            }
            if (mCountAfter > mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 13) {
                cardnumber.append(" ");
                System.out.println(cardnumber);
                ;
            } else if (mCountAfter < mCountBefore && mStartNumber == 20) {
                System.out.println(cardnumber);
                cardnumber.delete(cardnumber.length() - 1, cardnumber.length());

            }

            if (cardnumber.length() == 19) {
                //  s.delete(s.length()-1, s.length());
                String faq;
                Editable ab = new SpannableStringBuilder(cardnumber.toString().replace(" ", ""));
                if (lunaCheck(String.valueOf(ab)) == false) {
                    //editTextValidity.requestFocus();
                    editTextCardNumber.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                } else {
                    editTextValidity.requestFocus();
                    editTextCardNumber.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

                }
            }
}
```